# The character table of an abelian group

Tags: representation-theory, characters

I am attempting to construct the character table for $\mathbb{Z}_8$. I know a few things off the bat:

- Since $\mathbb{Z}_8$ is abelian, its conjugacy classes are singletons (i.e. we have eight classes)
- Since $\mathbb{Z}_8$ is abelian, all irreducible representations are one-dimensional

So we note that for $\pi_1, \dots, \pi_8$ as a list of irreducoble representations, we always have $\pi_1(g) = 1$ is the trivial representation. We also know that $\pi_i(0) = 1$ since $\pi_i$ is a homomorphism. So we have so far

$$$$\begin{vmatrix}
 & \{0\} & \{1\} & \{2\} & \{3\} & \{4\} & \{5\} & \{6\} & \{7\} \\
 \chi_1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  \chi_2 & 1 &  &  &  & & & &  \\
   \chi_3 & 1 & & & & & & &  \\
    \chi_4 & 1 & & & & & & &  \\
     \chi_5 & 1 & & & & & & &  \\
      \chi_6 &  1& & & & & & &  \\
       \chi_7 & 1 & & & & & & &  \\
        \chi_8 &  1 & & & & & & &  \\
\end{vmatrix}$$
$$

Now, how can we fill in the remaining rows? I understand that, in other cases, we can utilize the fact that $\pi_i$ is a homomorphism and so, or example, with $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$, if we have $\pi(0,1) = -1$ and $\pi(1,0) = -1$, then $\pi(1,1) = \pi\big[ (1,0) + (0,1) \big] = \pi(1,0)\pi(0,1) = (-1)(-1)=1$.

So assume $\chi_2(1) = -1$ and then, working out the details, it follows that we have

$$\begin{vmatrix}
 & \{0\} & \{1\} & \{2\} & \{3\} & \{4\} & \{5\} & \{6\} & \{7\} \\
 \chi_1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  \chi_2 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1  \\
   \chi_3 & 1 & & & & & & &  \\
    \chi_4 & 1 & & & & & & &  \\
     \chi_5 & 1 & & & & & & &  \\
      \chi_6 &  1& & & & & & &  \\
       \chi_7 & 1 & & & & & & &  \\
        \chi_8 &  1 & & & & & & &  \\
\end{vmatrix}$$

But beyond this point, I am lost because:

- If we assume $\chi_3(1) = 1$, then every value following it must be 1 (we already have this)
- If we assume $\chi_3(1) = -1$, then every value following it must alternate (we already have this)

Does anyone have any advice regarding this issue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to send $1$ to some number $x$ such that $x^8 = 1$. Have you considered some complex numbers?

Comment: @Joppy I suppose I've not encountered character tables with complex characters, although I could not see why that wouldn't be possible, since every representation sends a group element to $\mathbb{C}^\times$. So the roots of unity are the key here, I would assume.

Comment: In that case consider filling in the character table of $\Bbb{Z}_4$ first. The fourth root of unity is more famous than the eighth.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, all irreducible complex representations of $\mathbb{Z}_8$ are one-dimensional.

Furthermore, if $f:\mathbb{Z}_8\to G$ is a homomorphism, then $f(\mathbb{Z}_8)$ is cyclic of order $d$, where $d$ divides $8$.

So look for cyclic subgroups of $\mathbb{C}^\times$ of order $1,2,4,8$

and map $\mathbb{Z}_8$ onto each.